# How does baseline correction affect the absorbance in UV-vis spectrophotometry?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I did experiments with UV-Vis spectrophotometer to obtain a set of wavelengths vs absorbance for various concentrations. I found that I missed one trial of different concentration and I needed to obtain the data for the trial I missed. I remade a baseline solution and obtain the data I want. I need to graph the data from the trial I missed with the rest of data that I obtained before. I wonder if baseline correction from the previous data has effects on my another trial that did not run at the same time. Although I use the same concentration of solution for baseline solution, it will not lead to exactly the same data with the other data I did before.

I wonder if the baseline correction affects the absorbance of my new data and can I compare the new data with the previous data that has the same concentration baseline but not run at the same time?

Comment: If I understand ..... obviously you have to assume that your baseline solution (what is? Usually just solvent but it could have been a matrix) was correctly prepared in both cases.